# speech brain with voxlingua107 is not working properly

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I'm using voxlingua107 to detect language from audio
first it works fine but after a while I tried downloading an audio file with Spanish but it detects English !

```
class AudioMixin:
    def detect_language(self, path) -> str:
        language_id = EncoderClassifier.from_hparams(source="TalTechNLP/voxlingua107-epaca-ecapa", savedir='media/tmp')

        # Download Thai language sample from Omniglot and cvert to suitable form
        signal = language_id.load_audio(path)
        prediction =  language_id.classify_batch(signal)
        return prediction[3]
```

that's the code and I've no idea what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Why do you think that you are doing something wrong?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I updated the question
it detects wrong languages

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://huggingface.co/TalTechNLP/voxlingua107-epaca-tdnn#limitations-and-bias), VoxLingua107 is not a good dataset, it's an automatically collected YouTube dataset. Spanish data is quite small (39 hours) compared to other languages, you can't expect it to have good predictions with Spanish audio. One more thing, you did nothing wrong, the model is working properly, it's just not good enough.